# Cómo actualizar el DataBindings cuando el Dataset (origen de datos) retornó vacío y el usuario cambia el valor en el control en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, binding, dataset

Tengo un formulario que contiene muchos objetos en pantalla (y no quiero crear una propiedad "Get, Set" para cada uno), estoy usando DataBindings para estos, aquí solo muestro un ejemplo simple de lo que necesito.

Supongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("myConxion");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string cmd = "select id, nombre, apellido from Empleados where id = 5";
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cnn))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.Dispose();
        }

        #region Limpiar los DataBindings

        textId.DataBindings.Clear();
        textNombre.DataBindings.Clear();
        textApellido.DataBindings.Clear();

        #endregion

        #region Agregar el DataBindings a los Controles.

        textId.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "id", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
        textNnombre.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "nombre", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);
        textApellido.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "apellido", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty);

        #endregion
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(this,ex.Message, "ERROR", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

Cuando consulta la base de datos, y `da.Fill(ds);` recupera los datos en el DataSet, todo funciona bien, estos datos se muestran en "TextBox" "ComboBox" etc...

Pero cuando `da.Fill(ds);` no encontró datos, los "TextBox" "ComboBox" obviamente estarán vacío, PERO si el usuario en tiempo de ejecución agrega un valor a cualquiera de los "TextBox" "ComboBox"...

> **¿Cómo puedo hacer para insertar ese valor en el DataSet(ds), inmediatamente el usuario cambia el valor en el "TextBox" "ComboBox",
>   de manera automática?** (Este comportamiento hace exactamente eso  y
>   funciona bien **si el DataSet no está vacío**).

**Nota:** cuando digo "inmediatamente el usuario cambia el valor en los "TextBox" "ComboBox".. ese valor se debe insertar en el DataSet" Simplemente necesito que se inserte en el DataSet, "no estoy hablando de que se deba insertar en la base de datos" Para ello utilizo un procedimiento diferente.

Podrían ayudarme con este enfoque por favor.

Ambiente: 
.NetFramework 4.0, Visual Studio C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes agregar un registro nuevo si no retorna nada la consulta a la base de datos.

```
da.Fill(ds);

//verificar si la tabla no contiene registro
//agregar un registro nuevo con columnas vacias.
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    var row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
```

Me falto está sentencia

```
    ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: Gracias, al agregar esta Linea, ha funcionado. Saludos!